# Why is this transform.position reset between frames

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-development

So, my issue is as follows:

I'm developing a very simple 2D game as I'm quite new to Unity. Basically, there is a knight, and there is a troll. I'm developing my custom AI for the troll and got stumped at the very beginning. I tried to make the troll sprite correctly rotate and walk towards the player (in Update()), but then it turned out that the troll game object doesn't move as much as a millionth of a unit (although it rotates correctly)!

Now, what is special about my problem is the following: it's not about using localPosition instead of position (the troll has no parents – pun intended), it's not about referencing the transform in the script via "[SerializeField]", it's not about working with static objects or messed-up prefab coordinates or any of the other issues I've found in my desperate 10-hour search on the Internet. No, the issue is that I HAVE the troll transform in my code, I modify it successfully, but then it fails to be applied to the in-game troll object. Let that sink in – I am **correctly** modifying the **correct** transform (checked multiple times via debugging) but at the beginning of the next frame, all changes get magically reverted and the transform doesn't move the slightest.

I've made almost twenty modifications to my code in order to try and make it work (including separating stuff in different files as was suggested in a particular forum topic) but it just doesn't, and I can't think of anything else. Any help is very, very much appreciated.

```
public class EnemyController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Animator animator;
    [SerialiseField]
    private float walkingSpeed;
    [SerializeField]
    [Header("The aggro range of the enemy in Unity units.")]
    private float aggroRange;

    private float dir;

    private Transform playerTransform;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Aggro(playerTransform, aggroRange))
        {
            //WALKING:
            WalkTowards(playerTransform, walkingSpeed); 
        }
    }

    private void WalkTowards(Transform targetTransform, float walkingSpeed)
    {
        animator.SetBool("IsRunning", false);
        dir = 0.0f;

        //Get the direction (left or right)
        if (targetTransform.position.x < transform.position.x) //Left
        {
            dir = -1.0f;
            //Flip the sprite to the left
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, 180.0f, 0.0f);
        }
        else //Right
        {
            dir = 1.0f;
            //Flip the sprite to the right
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        }

        transform.position = new Vector3(
            transform.position.x + (walkingSpeed * dir * Time.deltaTime),
            transform.position.y,
            transform.position.z
        );

        Debug.Log(
            string.Format("Troll 1 position:\nx: {0:#.##}",  transform.position.x) +
            string.Format(" y: {0:#.##}", transform.position.y) +
            string.Format(" z: {0:#.##}", transform.position.z)
        );
    }
}
```

(NOTE: Aggro() is a custom method that determines when the enemy aggros; not      included in the code as it is irrelevant to the issue)

So basically, transform.position gets changed correctly in the script and stays that way until the end of the method, but at the beginning of the next frame – i.e. when WalkTowards() gets called again, the transform.position remains the same as it was at the beginning of the last frame – as if no calculations or changes were ever made.

Comment: How did you check you were modifying the correct transform? Also, can you include a `Debug.Log("playerTransform.gameObject.scene == null check: " + (playerTransform.gameObject.scene == null));` at the top of Update() and let us know what it outputs?

Comment: @Ruzihm Thank you for your answer! playerTransform.gameObject.scene == null returns false. I know it is the correct transform as I checked its information (name, coordinates etc) in the debugger window and they were all matching with the real one; I also tried explicitly referencing it with [SerializeField] at one point and still had the transform.position problem. :(

Comment: I made a typo, can you check this instead: `Debug.Log("playerTransform.gameObject.scene.name == null check: " + (playerTransform.gameObject.scene.name == null));` :)

Comment: @Ruzihm Sure thing, but it still returns false. :/

Comment: Seems like something else is overwriting your changes. You haven't shared enough code to indicate what that could be.  One place to start could be disabling all non-player, non-troll (and not their ancestor) gameobjects and disabling all the non `EnemyController` components on the player and troll (and their ancestors). This should result in the transform value not being reset unexpectedly. then, you could enable components on those two gameobjects and then re-enable other gameobjects until the problem reappears. that will hopefully indicate the culprit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ruzihm,

You were right!!! Turns out the Animator component of the troll was causing the issue – "Apply root motion" was off, I turned it on and the position gets correctly updated now. Thank you ever so much for the help!

Example:

[image: Animator component in inspector]

Comment: Glad you found the answer!  added an example image of the "Apply Root Motion" that I found in the unity docs.